# Can/should I use mod_rewrite to change the paths of links on a local Dev environment? (Kohana)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, kohana

First time collaborating on a large project: I may be in over my head.

All the links on the site broke when I try to run the code on my local machine.

/localhost/dir/file need to become /localhost/appname/html/dir/file

I changed APPPATH, SYSPATH &tc to reflect the dir change & that all works now, but the html/css/js links are all broken still. I think I need to change .htaccess & mod_rewrite to prepend appname/html/ to the links, but perhaps not?

---

edit: I was able to get some of the links working using the html `<base>` tag, the ones still not working seem to be created using Kohana classes, so I'm guessing there is a variable somewhere I still need to change.

Comment: why you have appname/html? could you add a hostname and configure apache to make it point to your subdirectory?

Comment: maybe? Yes probably, now that I think about it. That would be the best solution. Foolish I am.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct thing to do would be to use url::base() to generate the links. That would make the application more resilient to changes. But given that you're working on existing code, using mod_rewrite is a pragmatic approach, nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I thought so but I can't seem to get it to work. It should affect all links: css & js as well as anchor tags &tc?

Comment: You may need to change the config file for kohana so that `url::base()` knows about your changes to the base site URL.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding this JS to the ready function:

```
$( "[href]" ).attr("href",function(){ return "http://kohana/index.php" + $( this ).attr( "href" ); });
```

Terrible, I know. If anyone has a better solution I will be glad.